# Right definition of HashMap for static variables

Tags: java, hashmap

I have trouble with logical definition of the `HashMap`.

For example I create the following class to store some mandatory data, I just wanna know that is it good implementation or not? I used static `HashMap` because I need these `HashMaps` all over the time since my application is alive.

```
public abstract class DataTable {
    private static HashMap<String, String[]> mainData = new HashMap<String, String[]>();

    public static void putData(String[] data) {
        // put some data
    }

    public static String[] getData(String alias) {
        // return entered data with the given alias
    }
}
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated...

Comment: Well, having a static Map which holds a bunch of data accessible for everybody quite beats the purpose of object orientation. By the way your putData method is missing the key argument.

Comment: what is the purpose of making the methods and member variables static? A static variable means that all instances of that class share that variable. If you mean to have more than one instance of this class and they have their own copies of mainData, I do not suggest using static variables

Comment: no this is categorically **not** *good for multithreaded application*, this is exactly the **opposite** of how you would do something for a concurrent system. Put the keyboard down, and research the `java.util.concurrent` packages, then read up on why `static singletons` are harmful.

Comment: @anguyen: It's not that "all instances share that variable" - it's that the variable isn't associated with *any* instance, but with the type instead.

Comment: @JonSkeet: interesting, what is the difference both functionally and jvm-implementation-wise?

Comment: @anguyen: The difference is that your expression of it suggests that there has to be at least *one* instance for the static variable to be "shared" by... whereas in fact the static variable doesn't require any instances at all. Instances are *irrelevant* to it.

Answer (score -1):

Your static understanding is ok.

And your methods (setters and getters) should be

```
 public static void putData(String key ,String[] data) {
           mainData.put(key, data);
        }

 public static HashMap<String, String[]> getData(String alias) {
            return mainData;
        }
```

Of course ,obviously proper gauridng and exception handling is mandatory.

Update:As you mentioned in comment,that you are asking about thread safety on map use [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

```
Map<String, String[]> mainData = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String[]>();
```

Which is a

> A hash table supporting full concurrency of retrievals and adjustable expected concurrency for updates.

[A nice article on diff](http://www.journaldev.com/122/hashmap-vs-concurrenthashmap-%E2%80%93-example-and-exploring-iterator)

Comment: Thanks, I know how to set getter and setter. I just wanna know that is it good implementation for multithread application?